# Apache .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite this url schema

```
http://www.example.com/a/b/c/d.php?param=hi
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/a/b/d.php?type=c&param=hi
```

It's possible with mod_rewrite in .htaccess?

Thanks a lot for yours help!

[MORE DETAILS]

The base url of site is `http://www.example.com/a/b/`, and i have two type of customers, privates & sellers. I ask if is possible for customers call this url `http://www.example.com/a/b/private/index.php`, and internally rewrite it, with htaccess, to `http://www.example.com/a/b/index.php?cust=private` preserving the other GET parameters.

Comment: That is just simply a redirect from a URL to b URL. Maybe more info on what you expect to happen would be helpful. Is it supposed to redirect or or not etc?

Comment: Ok, sorry i have provided few details. The base url of site is http://www.example.com/a/b/, and i have two type of customers, privates & sellers. I ask if is possible for customers call this url http://www.example.com/a/b/private/index.php, and internally rewrite it, with htaccess, to http://www.example.com/a/b/index.php?cust=private preserving the other GET parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the URL is always the same you can literally just write it one for one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^a/b/private/index\.php$ /a/b/index.php?cust=private [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the Panama Jack's answer this is the standard rule for rewriting all page,

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ $2.php?cust=$1 [QSA]
```